# Find all occurrences of where a value is not in the database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of information which contains ranking information e.g.

```
Id  |  Keyword  | Url                                 |  
=======================================================
1   | google    | https://www.google.co.uk/           |
2   | google    | https://maps.google.co.uk/          |
3   | google    | https://www.facebook.com/Google/    |
4   | google    | https://www.youtube.com/user/Google |
5   | pizza     | https://www.pizzahut.co.uk/         |
6   | pizza     | https://www.dominos.co.uk/          |
7   | pizza     | https://www.just-eat.co.uk/         |
8   | pizza     | https://www.yell.com                |
```

I need to be able find all the keywords that don't rank for a specific URL, so in the table above if I was looking for keywords that rank for https://www.google.co.uk/ it would only return one result of **pizza**.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Can you please explain more about why only "pizza" is returned for "https://www.google.co.uk/"?

Comment: Sure, in my example above I only looking for keywords that don't rank for the url 'https://www.google.co.uk/'. In my example above pizza is the only keyword that doesn't have a `Url` for that keyword. Does that make more sense? :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the keywords that are not there for a given `URL`, here is one method:

```
select keyword
from t
group by keyword
having sum(case when url = $url) = 0;
```

Alternatively, if you have a separate list of keywords:

```
select kw.keyword
from keywords kw
where not exists (select 1 from t where t.url = $url and t.keyword = kw.keyword);
```

You can also implement this method using a subquery:

```
select kw.keyword
from (select distinct keyword from t) kw
where not exists (select 1 from t where t.url = $url and t.keyword = kw.keyword);
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I needed, thanks :) the second query is one I am using but I am interested to try the first one out as it might be quicker. Problem is I am getting an error: "
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') = 0' at line 4"

Comment: Don't worry about it's more than fast enough now I have the correct indexes in please. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return any one of your `pizza` record you can try this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(Url) NOT LIKE 'google' LIMIT 1
```

If instead you want all the results that don't match `google` you just need to remove the `LIMIT`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(Url) NOT LIKE 'google'
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to match based on the URL they are ranking for (URL column) rather than the keyword.